# Updating object fields from separate processes? (kind of upsert)

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have `Task` objects with several attributes. These tasks are bounced between several processes (using Celery) and I'd like to update the task status in a database.

Every update should update only non-NULL attributes of the object. So far I have something like:

```
def del_empty_attrs(task):
    for name in (key for key, val in vars(task).iteritems() if val is None):
        delattr(task, name)


def update_task(session, id, **kw):
    task = session.query(Task).get(id)
    if task is None:
        task = Task(id=id)

    for key, value in kw.iteritems():
        if not hasattr(task, key):
            raise AttributeError('Task does not have {} attribute'.format(key))
        setattr(task, key, value)

    del_empty_attrs(task)  # Don't update empty fields
    session.merge(task)
```

However, get either `IntegrityError` or `StaleDataError`. What the right way to do this?

I *think* the problem is that every process has its own `session`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: AFAIK, if the field value has not changed `SA` will not include this field in the `UPDATE` statement. So maybe you just do not call `setattr` for those with `value = None` instead of deleting attributes: `if not(value is None): setattr(task, key, value)`?

Answer (score 0):

a lot more detail would be needed to say for sure, but there is a race condition in this code:

```
def update_task(session, id, **kw):
    # 1.
    task = session.query(Task).get(id)

    if task is None:
        # 2.
        task = Task(id=id)

    for key, value in kw.iteritems():
        if not hasattr(task, key):
            raise AttributeError('Task does not have {} attribute'.format(key))
        setattr(task, key, value)

    del_empty_attrs(task)  # Don't update empty fields

    # 3.
    session.merge(task)
```

If two processes both encounter #1, and find the object for the given id to be `None`, they both proceed to create a new `Task()` object with the given primary key (assuming `id` here is the primary key attribute).  Both processes then race down to the `Session.merge()` which will attempt to emit an INSERT for the row.  One process gets the INSERT, the other one gets an IntegrityError as it did not INSERT the row before the other one did.

There's no simple answer for how to "fix" this, it depends on what you're trying to do.  One approach might be to ensure that no two processes work on the same pool of primary key identifiers.  Another would be to ensure that all INSERTs of non-existent rows are handled by a single process.

Edit: other approaches might involve going with an "optimistic" approach, where SAVEPOINT (e.g. Session.begin_nested()) is used to intercept an IntegrityError on an INSERT, then continue on after it occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid inter-process locking. Thought there might be a way to do this with transactions.

Comment: well transaction isolation does a great job for UPDATE statements against a common row (e.g. REPEATABLE READ) - though even then, modern systems tend to take an "optimistic" approach, that is a conflicting UPDATE will throw an exception on commit, rather than locking.  For INSERTs, going to SERIALIZABLE will make it such that a transaction will not see rows "appear" or "disappear" within the scope of that transaction, but again as far as "locking", it's not guaranteed that you wouldn't just get an integrity error on commit.

Comment: so all that being said, you can take that merge() and run it within a "with session.begin_nested()", catch the IntegrityError, then continue with the row.   That's going with the optimistic approach and just dealing with the error.